# Comparing Sets with Arrays inside

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, foundation

In Objective-C you can easily initialize `NSSet` objects that contains `NSArray` objects as elements. And you can easily compare those `NSSet` objects thanks to the *isEqual:* method.

Now in Swift, which is much more strongly typed, we can no longer do this. The following declaration will receive a "Type [Int] does not conform to protocol Hashable" error.

```
var set: Set<[Int]>
```

I am now trying to compare the equality of two groups of arrays that contain a bunch of Int numbers, I want to take advantage of the "isEqual:" idea with Set and Array in Swift, What should I do?

Comment: Well I thought, just make an Array extension and make it `Hashable`, but as this requires a `var hashValue`, it cannot be defined in another module, sadly.

Comment: Not true, `hashValue` can be a computed property as well, which can be added in extensions without issues.

Comment: @DavideDeFranceschi Yes, but `hashValue` needs to be declared `public`, which cannot be added in extensions.

Comment: `extension NSArray: Equatable {}
    public func ==(lhs: NSArray, rhs: NSArray) -> Bool {
     return lhs.isEqualToArray(rhs as [AnyObject])
    }
    extension NSArray: Hashable {
     var hashable: Int {
      return 1
     }
    }
    
    let fooSet: Set<NSArray> = [NSArray(array: [1, 2])]
    fooSet.dynamicType
`
This compiles on my playground (sorry can't format long code in comments?)

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is thinking: why can't I do that with the standard library?
`Set` requires `Hashable` items, which have to be `Equatable` as well. This means that doing `Set<Array<T>>` would require *Any* `Array` to be checked for equality with others. But if `T` is not `Equatable`, how do you compare them? Not being able to (still?) declare conditional extensions leads to this :(

I think your best bet (without messing too much with extensions on the standard library) is either use `NSSet`/`NSArray` in Swift too, or define at least one of the two parts (`Set` and `Array`) as a wrapper.